# Access-Control-Allow-Origin and document.domain not working

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, cross-domain, access-control

I have an iframe inside a PHP page and I am trying to access a parent element from within the iframe, but always get this error in the Console:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   https://subdomain.domain.com from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I have read every single search result on Google's first page around `Same Origin policy` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` but that doesn't seem to be solving my problem. I am still getting the same error.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` into my iframe content.
2. Added `document.domain` into my iframe content.

Has anybody else had similar problem? What can I do to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://b.example.com');
?>

<script>
    function receiveMessage(event) {
        if (event.origin !== "https://a.example.com")
            return;
    }
    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
</script>


<div>
    <button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="close">×</button>
</div>

<iframe name="myIframe" class="myIframe"
        src="https://b.example.com" width="100%" height="600px"
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="">
</iframe>

</div>
```

Script in b.example.com

```
<script>
    window.parent.$('.close').click(function () {
        var thisObj = this;
        if (!feedbackLoaded) {
            $('#openFeedback').click();
            feedbackLoaded = true;
            $('#feedbackForm .close').click(function () {
                window.parent.$.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(thisObj);
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            window.parent.$.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(thisObj);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: processing parent window from iframe always was a bad practice. Even when domain is the same

Comment: I understand you but when you are working on a ten years old application with millions of users per day, you know most of the minor modifications are workaround rather than a proper solution :) it is what it is and we have to find a solution with the existing system

Comment: ok :) Then you have to add instructions to parent window (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) should be there. Then you can communicate with it over postMessage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Hi @AlexSlipknot I am trying to use the example given in your link but for me it says: `Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined
    at test.php:4` on my iframe that I am defining on my parent page.

Comment: I think you missed some selector. Because you have message 'Undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Regardless to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage you can implement communication between your document and iframe.

In this case you have to specify **all operations** that will be available on parent window. Here is an example:

Parent window:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function receiveMessage(event) {
        console.log(event);
        if (event.data.message === 'Hello world') {
            $('#openFeedback').click();
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
</script>


<div>
    <button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="close">×</button>
</div>

<iframe name="myIframe" class="myIframe"
        src="http://b.test.dev" width="100%" height="600px"
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

And subdomain in iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    window.parent.postMessage({message: 'Hello world'}, 'http://test.dev');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also you should provide some security check for iframe identity like you added in your example. In that case you don't need to add cross-origin header

Comment: it's strange it worked for me without adding any event listener on parent and adding postMessage on iframe. All I did was added the jquery file in head of parent and it's working fine.

Comment: Sorry I have been running both on same domain. Let me give it a go in Prod

Comment: So have you succeed? :)

Comment: Hi buddy you have mentioned "you have to specify all operations that will be available on parent window." Unfortunately I cannot move the application logic to parent window. It has to stay in the iframe. But as you can see, code in the iframe is trying to access an element of the parent page and I am getting cross domain error

Comment: Calling `$('#openFeedback').click();` from parent means I'll also need to move the `<div id=openFeedback></div>` from iframe to parent window.

Comment: Ah, ok understood. Unfortunately you cannot do that. The only method to communicate with parent window at not same domain is postMessage

Comment: gotcha! I used window.postMessage and eventListener both on iframe as well as parent and it seems to be working all fine. Thanks very much :)

Comment: @PHPDev Congratulations! :)